# What is wrong with: select CONVERT(date,N'13/01/2016')

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I used SQL Server 2008 R2 when I run the statement

```
select CONVERT(date, N'13/01/2016')
```

I get this error. Could anyone help please?

Error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select CONVERT(DATE,N'01/13/2016')
```

Comment: Format of the given date is dd/mm/yyyy but you need to give is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Thanks alot , I have tried all participations and work fine for me thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have an issue with the formatting of the string literal that represents the date. These are very often dependent on language and/or regional settings.

Try to use the **ISO-8601** format `YYYYMMDD` to avoid those troubles:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, N'20160113')
```

Comment: Thanks alot , I have tried all participations and work fine for me thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Convert NVarchar type to Date-time,
You can try below:

```
DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(10)
SET @StartDate='13/01/2016'     
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, @StartDate, 103)
```

Comment: Thanks alot , I have tried all participations and work fine for me thanks all